# Is ‎‎$‎\mu‎$‎ ‎complete ‎measure?‎

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

‎Let $f$ ‎be‎ ‎measurable ‎and ‎$f=g$ ‎$‎‎\mu‎$‎‎-‎a.‎e. ‎If  also we ‎have ‎been ‎that‎ $g‎$ ‎is ‎measurable‎, Is ‎‎$‎\mu‎$‎ ‎complete ‎measure?‎

I ‎think ‎that ‎we ‎should ‎assume ‎that‎ $‎\mu‎$ ‎is ‎not ‎complete ‎measure ‎and ‎find a‎ ‎contrary ‎example, ‎How ‎you?‎‎
‎(‎‎See : ‎2.11 ‎proposition ‎of ‎Folland‎'s real ‎analysis)‎‎

Comment: Modify $f$ on a non-measurable null set.

Comment: Bounties are nice, but did you try to follow @Martin's hint above? If you did and were stopped, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a null-set and alet $f$ be its indicator function. Then every indicator function $g$ of a subset $B$ of $A$ equals $f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. So $B$ is measurable and $\mu$ complete.

Of course, this has to hold for all measurable functions $f$, not just a given one.